# ChromeDriver with Selenium displays a blank page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium(Java) with Chrome to access the following website:

https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html?targetUrl=/

The Problem is that it always displays a blank page. Here is my Code:

```
ChromeOptions cap = new ChromeOptions();
cap.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\Application\\chrome.exe");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32beta\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(cap);


driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.manage().window().maximize();


    try {
        driver.get("https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html?targetUrl=/");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Every other website I have tried works just fine, but this one doesn't want to show up. I have tried to access this website from Firefox, Chrome and Edge, which also show a blank page. I am using Selenium(3.141.59), ChromeDriver(81.0.4044.20) and Chrome Beta(81.0.4044.62).
Here is the HTML Code when I ispect the website:

[image: Webpage is blank]

Comment: body is empty, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this site can detect Selenium and do not open with it.

You can hide it using Chrome Options. Try adding arguments like this before openning the url:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: This solved my problem. Much appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

It works with [selenium stealth](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/) and the following options

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Check if the page you requested returns a successful HTTP status code like 200. In my case, it returned a 40x error which resulted in a blank page.